# Python Multiprocess Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, pickle

I had a problem for multiprocess, and below it is the code that I used to perform a test:

```
import multiprocessing


class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def add(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        return self.x + self.y


class Worker(Test):
    def do_me(self,x,y):
        return self.add(x,y)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    job = Worker()

    # #single process
    # x = 1
    # y = 9
    # result = job.do_me(x,y)
    # print "%2d +%2d = %2d "%(x,y,result)

    #multiprocess
    x = [1,2,3]
    y = [9,7,5]

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    retults = [ pool.map(job.do_me, ((x[i], y[i]),)) for i in range(len(x)) ]
    print results
```

For single process, it will work fine. However, for multiprocess, it did not. The error msg is:

```
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemet hod failed
```

I searched here, but i did not quite understand the machanism. Could someone give me more help? Cheers.

Comment: Your "here" link is nonexistent. Where did you search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error suggests, you can't pickle instance methods. The problem is this line:

```
pool.map(job.do_me, ((x[i], y[i]),)) for i in range(len(x))
```

The mechanism behind this is that when the `map` function sends the function (the first argument) to all of the workers, it has to serialize it to data somehow, so it's using a mechanism called [pickling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickle_%28Python%29). There are other mechanisms, this is the a very common one in Python).

When it's trying to pickle an instance method (specifically method `do_me`, of instances of type `Worker`) and send it to the pool (for the workers to know what method they're supposed to execute), it fails. Because you can't pickle instance methods.

You can fix this by moving the method to the module level (removing the `Worker` class):

```
def do_me(test_instance):
    return test_instance.add(x,y)
```

Now we don't have access to `self`, since we're using the test_instance that's sent here explicitly, so this method isn't bound to the `Test` class anymore... Or put in other words - **this isn't an instance method anymore**. Now make sure you re-factor everything to work as you plan.

The `Test` class should have something along this structure to keep the list comprehension in the argument construction to `pool.map` simple:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def add(self,x,y):
        return self.x + self.y
```

Adn then  calling it like this:

```
results = pool.map(do_me, [Test(x[i], y[i]) for i in range(len(x))])
```

### Full code:

```
import multiprocessing


class Test():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def add(self):
        return self.x + self.y


def do_me(test_instance):

    return test_instance.add()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    x = [1,2,3]
    y = [9,7,5]

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    results = pool.map(do_me, [Test(x[i], y[i]) for i in range(len(x))])
    print results
```

### Some notes:

1. `pool.map` already returns a `list`
2. `__init__` is the standard place to **init**ialize the object data (x, y in your case).
3. The function `pool.map` is using is applied to each item of the iterable, so it should be a single-argument function (you can use a tuple, but you have to unpack it).

Comment: I added a bit more details, but if you'll be more specific I'll be more specific :)

Comment: @ReutSharabani , you also need a specific argument for `self` in the `pool.map` call -- you can't just have two args once you've made `do_me` a function rather than a method!  That first arg had better be an instance of `Test`, BTW:-)

Comment: @AlexMartelli could happen to us all!

Comment: what I can see is, you missed *job.* in *pool.map* call. I did not understand this.

Also, if not using *map*, what other machanism or methods I can use?

Comment: @Victor.Li , see edits. I missed the fact you're using `Test`. I actually ended up writing the code and it's working now :)

You can tell him how to pickle, but this is not in the scope of a comment. Make sure to read this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

Comment: @ReutSharabani Thank you for the details. But I got error:
    *NameError: global name 'x' is not defined*

It may be raised from your defined function *add* where it has only one arg, right?

Comment: @ReutSharabani Excellent!!! 

I would want to say, your code is working. But I will test another case. That is, the Class Worker *should* be called ... Then the *Test* will be *Worker* in principle, right?

To confirm: it is verified that just change **Test** to **Worker** if I need to use **Worker**. In real case, **Test** defines common properties which should ONLY be called once. Wheareas Worker will reuse them, but be distributed by pool.

If I am wrong, please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Yup. Just think about it this way: If you want to use add, without knowing the object, how can you tell what is `self.x` ot `self.y`? You have to know what the entire object is. If you **don't need** `self.x` and `self.y` (or any other `self.something` - than this shouldn't be an instance method.

Comment: @ReutSharabani My mistake and misunderstanding before was ** passing  instance.method ** to pool. However the code did not work, as you said the pool could not find it (but why not? Why not just accepting what it received?).

Comment: While it's perfectly reasonable you *can* do what you want with an instance method, it doesn't work out-of-the-box. You have to manually implement the pickling and unpickling process. Read here: http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/552476-why-cant-you-pickle-instancemethods